# Replace multiple text with specific text

Tags: javascript

I wanted to replace the text if the `userInput` matches the following text

`Ok`, `Ok Got it`, `Next` & `Confirm` with `Yes`

Below is the sample code.

const userInput =  "Ok Next"

I tried with `userInput.replace('ok', 'yes')` it works only for `Ok`.

How I make it work for other words ??

Comment: You can do it with [regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ( helpful tool: https://regex101.com/ ) and a pattern like: `^([oO]k|[nN]ext)$`

Comment: You can create an array of strings that you want to match with and then use `includes` to check if it includes or not. If it exist then change object's property value. Simple

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a regular expression to the first parameter of a `String.prototype.replace` call, and use the `i` flag to specify case insensitivity.

For example:

```
userInput.replace(/ok/i, 'yes')
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_global_and_ignore_with_replace) for more information.

Comment: this is not working, can you provide me an working demo

Answer (score 1):

Not so clean, but this should make you started.

```js
const watchedInputs = ["Ok", "Ok Got it", "Next", "Confirm", "Yes", "Ok Next"];

function checkUserInput(answer){
  console.log(watchedInputs.includes(answer));
}

checkUserInput("Ok Next");
```

However, I am just guessing that your approach here isn't solid. You should place a radio button that ask for a YES or NO question.

I cannot imagine all possible user inputs that you cannot catch to replace with a YES.

If you still wants user to type on, this should only as a comment / remarks field.

Answer (score 0):

As @kapitan answered you can use `.include` to check if the string contain a certain pattern, it may work here but can generate some bug later. What you can do is check each word in isolation using regex. Also, I suggest you to compare input in lowercase or uppercase to support user's input with caps somewhere into. Here your yes value is stocked in `response` :

```js
const userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const words = ["ok", "ok got it", "next", "confirm", "ok next"];
const wordsRegex = RegExp("\\b(" + words.join("|") + ")\\b");
let response;

function check(){
  
  if (wordsRegex.test(userInput.value.toLowerCase())){   //check in lowercase

  response = "yes";
  output.innerHTML = response;
  }
  
  else{
  output.innerHTML = "no";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<input type="test" id="userInput" placeholder="Type here">
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Check">
<p id="output"></p>
```